# could not establish a secure connection with my given url in my app

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

i have a form that contains hidden values that needs to be posted to the url when the form is submitted.
the url is for card payment and its for the security purpose,
so when attempt to do the process with my app to open the url and posting the hidden values with it , it gives cant establish secure connection and the app crashes.
but when i do this in my pc browser it works fine there is no error.

this is my form:

```
<form name="hidden_form" id="hidden_form" action="{{ bookings.payment.ACSUrl }}" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="{{ bookings.payment.PaReq }}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="{{ bookings.payment.TermUrl }}" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="{{ bookings.payment.md }}" />
</form>
```

the url is :
https://webapp.securetrading.net/acs/visa.cgi
using my app(phonegap)
when the form is submitted it takes time and hits the url but error prompts could not establish secure connection  followed by the url and the app crash.
help required 
i hope every one can understand what iam trying to say

Answer (score 0):

For phonegap, you will need to add the whitelist plugin (it used to be in core, so you probably have it already):

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Help docs are listed here:

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_access_elements.md.html

You will also need to add this line in your config.xml after installing the plugin:

```
<access origin="https://securetrading.net/" subdomains="true"/>
```

Edit:

To be able to submit the form without it opening the device web browser, you need to submit the form via JavaScript.  Since you tagged you are using jQuery, here is code to do that:

```
    $(document).on('submit', 'form.hidden_form', function() {            
            $.ajax({
                url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                dataType: 'json',
                data    : $(this).serialize(),
                success : function( data ) {
                             alert('Submitted');
                },
                error   : function( xhr, err ) {
                             alert('Error');     
                }
            });    


return false;
    });
```

EDIT - 4/12:

Here is a whole different example that works.  I get a 500 error code from your URL because I would assume I am sending invalid data, but it makes it to the site and the data is passed:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,300,400italic,500,700,700italic,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Onsen UI Forum Help by Munsterlander</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-beta.8/css/onsenui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-beta.8/css/onsen-css-components.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI-dist/2.0.0-beta.8/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>

    <script>
        function formHelp(){
            my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
            my_form.name='myForm';
            my_form.method='POST';
            my_form.action='https://webapp.securetrading.net/acs/visa.cgi';

            my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
            my_tb.type='HIDDEN';
            my_tb.name='PaReq';
            my_tb.value='000';
            my_form.appendChild(my_tb);

            my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
            my_tb.type='HIDDEN';
            my_tb.name='TermUrl';
            my_tb.value='000';
            my_form.appendChild(my_tb);

            my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
            my_tb.type='HIDDEN';
            my_tb.name='MD';
            my_tb.value='000';
            my_form.appendChild(my_tb);

            document.body.appendChild(my_form);
            my_form.submit();
        }

    </script>    
</head>

<body>

<ons-tabbar id="myNav">
  <ons-tab page="home.html" active="true">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-home"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Home</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="fav.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-star"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Favorites</span>
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="settings.html">
    <ons-icon icon="ion-gear-a"></ons-icon>
    <span style="font-size: 14px">Settings</span>
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
<ons-template id="home.html">
  <p>Home</p>
  <ons-button onclick="formHelp()">Submit JS Form</ons-button>
  <div style="padding:10px;">    
  </div>
  <form name="hidden_form" id="hidden_form" action="https://webapp.securetrading.net/acs/visa.cgi" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="PaReq" value="000" />
      <input type="hidden" name="TermUrl" value="000" />
      <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="000" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
</ons-template>
<ons-template id="fav.html">
  <p>Fav</p>
</ons-template>
<ons-template id="settings.html">
  <p>Settings</p>
</ons-template>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" id="com.example.helloworld" version="1.0.0">
  <name>Onsen 2.0 Quick Start</name>
  <description/>
  <author/>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
  <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000"/>
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud"/>
  <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
  <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false"/>
  <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray"/>
  <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PageLength" value="0"/>
  <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page"/>
  <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated"/>
  <feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
  </feature>
  <preference name="UIWebViewDecelerationSpeed" value="normal"/>
  <preference name="monaca:AndroidIsPackageNameSeparate" value="false"/>
  <preference name="monaca:targetFamilyiPhone" value="1"/>
  <preference name="monaca:targetFamilyiPad" value="1"/>
</widget>
```

These are nothing more than the quickstart apps and all appears to be communicating fine with your site.  I would think the most important part that you may not have, would be:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Just monaca plugin, splashscreen plugin, and whitelist plugin are installed in the base package.

Comment: i did added this access tag and whitelist i already there, but the error remains, do you want to look at my config.xml ? @Munsterlander

Comment: one thing more do you have any idea about :
when i submit my form the action attr of the form takes me to the given url , and opens up with inappbrowser what i want to check is can i handle form submission with external browsers @munsterlander ?

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide you with code for form submission.  This will probably also resolve your whitelist error as I didn't realize you were going cross-browser - a whole different issue.

Comment: i need to redirect to the url as well i have to give all the responsibilities to the url am posting , i dont think ajax req would help me in this it can only happen by form posting to the url and the url should be open externally for the secure purpose as the default browser gives me secure connection cant establish. @munsterlander

Comment: Hybrid apps are nothing more than a mini-webbrowser wrapped for plugins.  When the form is posting to your URL, it is opening the device web browser.  Currently (example only), you are trying to make Firefox pass information to Internet Explorer and back and forth.  That is why you are getting errors.  So you have to have the URL open within your app using InAppBrowser.  This therefore resolves the cross-browser errors and security issues.  Check out:  http://developer.telerik.com/featured/securing-phonegapcordova-hybrid-mobile-app/ for more info.

Comment: yes this could be one of the reason well thanks for your guidance. 
@munsterlander

Comment: the issue was with the whitlist plugin i just have to remove version=1 from <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"/> and it solved my issue @munsterlander :)

Comment: I am still getting the same problem, I have changed my config file tried given answer script but it always giving me an error only, can you please help me

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your error and any additional code surrounding your form?  I will set some code up real quick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am using same all the things above and still getting this `A secure connection could not be established. (http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr)` and my app is crash while form submit by javascript function getting into error function with status 0

Comment: Are you now using paypal?  If so, then this error is probably due to SSL/TTL api certificate.  Try using:  `api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com` instead.